# How can I get the data of this table from HackerRank and filter it by country of origin and score for then exporting it as a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning web **scraping** on Python and I decided to test my skills in the [HackerRank Leaderboard page](https://www.hackerrank.com/leaderboard), so I wrote the code below expecting no errors before adding the country restriction to the **`tester`** function for then exporting my csv file successfully.

But then the Python console replied:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

The error above corresponds to the line 29 from my code (`for i in table.find_all({'class':'ellipsis'}):`), so I decided to come here in order to ask for assistance, I'm afraid there could be more syntax or logic errors, so it's better to get rid of my doubts by getting a feedback from experts.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from random import randint

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 

#Declaring a variable for looping over all the pages
pages = np.arange(1, 93, 1)

a = pd.DataFrame()
#loop cycle

for url in pages:      

    #get html for each new page
    url ='https://www.hackerrank.com/leaderboard?page='+str(url)
    page = requests.get(url)
    sleep(randint(3,10))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    #get the table
    table = soup.find('header', {'class':'table-header flex'})
    headers = []
    
    #get the headers of the table and delete the "white space"
    for i in table.find_all({'class':'ellipsis'}):
        title = i.text.strip()
        headers.append(title)
    
    #set the headers to columns in a new dataframe 
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)
    
    rows = soup.find('div', {'class':'table-body'})
    #get the rows of the table but omit the first row (which are headers)
    for row in rows.find_all('table-row-wrapper')[1:]:
        data = row.find_all('table-row-column ellipsis')
        row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]  
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = row_data 
    
    #set the data of the Txn Count column to float
    Txn = df['SCORE'].values
    
    
    #combine all the data rows in one single dataframe
    a = a.append(pd.DataFrame(df))  
    
    def tester(mejora):
        mejora = mejora[(mejora['SCORE']>2250.0)] 
        return mejora.to_csv('new_test_Score_Count.csv') 
    
    tester(a)
```

Do you guys have any ideas or suggestions that could fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

the error states, that you table element is None. i'm guessing here but you cant get the table from the page with bs4 because it is loaded after with javascript. I would recommend to use selenium for this instead